# How to reproduce GridView in the same Layout?

Tags: android, gridview, layout-inflater

I have GridView to show some images. I want to reproduce the gridview but I couldn't do that. I see the first gridview but I don't see the second. To reproduce the GridView, I use LayoutInflater. LayoutInflater works well because I see the repeating parts on the screen but GridView doesn't repeat.

Can someone say me why GridView is not displayed?

Here is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ViewGroup parent;
static final String[] numbers = new String[] { 
    "A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
    "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
    "K", "L", "M", "N", "O"};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LinearLayout rl = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.outer);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
                this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 

    for(int i =1; i<3; i++){
        rl.addView(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.main2, parent, false), i );

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);}

    }
}
```

Here is my Main Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/outer"
>

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Main Layout Content"/>
```

Here is the child layout which has GridView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/outer">

<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Child Layout Content."/>
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="50dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

[image]

Thank you for you help.

Comment: If you're using the same id(R.id.gridView1) for finding the GridViews, that will make the gridView reference point only to the first GridView in the layout(the first inflated).

Comment: Hi @Luksprog. What should I do here to create gridview dynamically?

Comment: Look for the GridView in the inflated layout before you add it to the LinearLayout.